# How to save incoming textfile from client from websocket connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, websocket

I'm trying to implement a websocket server in node.js without using any framework.
Sending messages from client to server is working fine. But now I tried to send a text file from client to server. I can see the content on the server side by using console.log in the terminal.
But:

1. how can i get the file information ? (name, created/edited date, etc. ?)
2. how can i save the file ?

Client code:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var output, ws;

    //Display logging information in the document
    function log(s) {
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
        p.textContent = s;
        output.appendChild(p);

        //Also log information on the javascript console
        window.console.log(s);
    }

    //Send a message on the Websocket
    function sendMessage(msg) {
        console.log(ws.binaryType);
        ws.send(msg);
        console.log("Message sent");
    }

    //Initialize WebSocket connection and event handlers
    function setup() {
        output = document.getElementById("output");
        ws = new window.WebSocket("ws://localhost:9999/");

        //Listen for the connection open event then call the sendMessage function
        ws.onopen = function () {
            console.log("Connected");
            document.getElementById('fl').onchange = function() {
                sendMessage(document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').files[0]);
            };
            sendMessage("Hello Galileo!");
        }

        //Listen for the close connection event
        ws.onclose = function (e) {
            if(this.readyState == 2){
                console.log('Connection is closing (Closing Handshake).')
            }
            else if(this.readyState == 3){
                console.log('Connection closed. Has been closed or could not be opened.')
            }
            else{
                console.log('Unhandled ReadyState: ',this.readyState);
            }
            console.log("Disconnected: " + 
                       ' reason:' + e.reason + 
                       ' was clean:' + e.wasClean + 
                       ' code:' + e.code);
        }

        //Listen for connection errors
        ws.onerror = function (e) {
            console.log("Error: " + e);
        }

        //Listen for new messages arriving at the client
        ws.onmessage = function (e) {
            console.log("Message received: " + e.data);
            //Close the socket once one message has arrived
            ws.close();
        }

    }
    //Start running the example
    setup();

})();
```

HTML Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Websocket Echo Client</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Websocket Echo Client</h2>
<div id="output"></div>
<input type="file" id="fl"/>
<script src="websocket.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Server code

```
switch (opcode) {
        case opcodes.TEXT:
          this.payload = payload.toString("utf8");
          winston.log('info','Text:\r\n', this.payload);
          break;
        case opcodes.BINARY:
          console.log('info','File:\r\n', payload.toString("utf8"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the payload you're receiving on the server side does not contain the meta data about the file. I believe the `File` object is treated as a normal `Blob` with some extra meta data and the `ws.send` is only handling it like a `Blob` ([it has no special handling for `File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#send())).

The meta data can be accessed using

```
document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').files[0].name
document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').files[0].size
document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').files[0].type
```

And then send separately.

Comment: I Tracked the connection between server and client. The websocket protocol sends one frame and the data is chunked tcp. Do you know how i can reassemble the tcp data ? In node.js the socket.on"end" event is not emitted, because the fin is send via websocket frame and not tcp

Comment: @benu I think you would be well advised to ask that question seperatedly as it has little to do with this question and I am not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @benu If all you want to do is inspect websocket connections Chrome nowadays provides tooling for that.